# Replace one column with another in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a dataset that has more than 40 columns and I want to replace two columns data with another two columns of data and want to remove the existing one.

**Example Dataset:**

```
v_4        v5             s_5     vt_5     ex_5          pfv           pfv_cat
0-50      StoreSale     Clothes   8-Apr   above 100   FatimaStore       Shoes
0-50      StoreSale     Clothes   8-Apr   0-50        DiscountWorld     Clothes
51-100    CleanShop     Clothes   4-Dec   51-100      BetterUncle       Shoes
```

I want to replace the `v5` column with `pfv` and `s_51 with`pfv_cat`, by replace I mean`overwrite`

Here's what I have tried:

```
df.replace(df['v_5'].tolist(), df['pfv'].tolist())
df.replace(df['s_5'].tolist(), df['pfv_cat'].tolist())
```

But it doesn't work, it's just stuck and no input.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
df['v_5']=df['pfv']
df['s_5']=df['pfv_cat']
print(df)
```

**Input**

```
     v_4          v5    s_5         vt_5    ex_5             pfv        pfv_cat
0   0-50    StoreSale   Clothes     8-Apr   above100    FatimaStore     Shoes
1   0-50    StoreSale   Clothes     8-Apr   0-50        DiscountWorld   Clothes
2   51-100  CleanShop   Clothes     4-Dec   51-100      BetterUncle     Shoes
```

**Output**

```
v_4     v5  s_5     vt_5    ex_5    pfv     pfv_cat     v_5
0   0-50    StoreSale   Shoes   8-Apr   above100    FatimaStore     Shoes   FatimaStore
1   0-50    StoreSale   Clothes     8-Apr   0-50    DiscountWorld   Clothes     DiscountWorld
2   51-100  CleanShop   Shoes   4-Dec   51-100  BetterUncle     Shoes   BetterUncle
```

Comment: for this code it's just stuck and no input ... still the same

Comment: you need to `print(df)`, to see the changes. added that to the code now.